# How to list down all possibilities of a searched value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In my project we simply give Location Codes to room which also has a name. But there might be bunch of same named location with different specifications.

ex: Location Code : B2- 001 (B Column)
    Location Name : Loby ( C Column )

"B2" represents the floor number and the number coming after the "-" simply given to that room to form Location code which becomes unique for that room regardless of how many more same location name exists within the list of mine.

My problem is that I need a formula / macro simply to list all possible Location codes of written Location Name.

ex. "Loby" -
 B1-018
             B2-034
             B2-051

Finally, List (the sheet to look over/search the names and codes) and Results (where the list appears after writing down the Location Name) are going to be in two different sheets in a same working book.

Comment: No @pnuts, its about Excel.

Answer (score 0):

well, assuaming you number all your floors with a letter then a number, you can use a concatination of that to iterate over all the floor index possibilites like this:

```
Dim MyHotel As New Collection
For i = 1 To 100 'as much as floors numbers you have
    For j = 65 To 91 'as much as floor letters you have
        MyHotel.Add (Chr(j) & "-" & i) 'chr convert from number using ascii
    Next j
Next i

Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Select
i = 1
For Each Floor In MyHotel
    Cells(i, "A").Value = Floor
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really two ways to do this:

1. Go to the Data ribbon menu and enable Filter, then use the pull-down menu at the top of Column C and uncheck everything except "Loby". You can then copy-paste the room numbers onto your second sheet.
2. If you want a VBA macro, you can use something like this (and modify for everything you need)

```
Option Explicit

Sub LocationFilterCopy()
    Dim roomList As Range
    Dim destResults As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i, j As Long
    Dim locationFilter As String

    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set roomList = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Resize(lastRow, 1)
    Set destResults = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    j = 1
    locationFilter = "Loby"
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If roomList.Cells(i, 2).Value = locationFilter Then
            destResults.Cells(j, 1).Value = roomList.Cells(i, 1).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an array formula. Enter "Loby" in A1 of your result sheet, then enter the following formula in A2 using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and pull it down:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(List!$B$2:$B$10, MATCH(0, IF($A$1=List!$C$2:$C$10, COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, List!$B$2:$B$10), ""), 0)),"")
```

It assumes that your List sheet looks like this:-

[image]

and the result sheet should look like this:-

[image]